# C# Windows Application - User Settings on InitializeComponent()

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to use persisted user settings (.settings) within the rendering of the components i.e. `InitializeComponent()` - Visual Studios WinForms designer support function, designer.cs.

For example, if an option was unchecked last sessions, it should remain unchecked this time.

It is working fine if I first render the components of the form i.e. running `InitializeComponent()`, and then within the initializer class of the program set the properties using the user settings.
But this is not very tidy and would rather it all be rendered together within the same function.

Is there any reason this is not working? Maybe I am missing some kind of assembly reference that is required for it to work?

Please note, my `InitializeComponent()` function is in a separate namespace

Comment: Unclear what the problem is without posting any code.  InitializeComponent is created by the designer, so you shouldn't be mucking with it.

Comment: need some code to check ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue.

Was a problem in using both `.Checked` and `.CheckState` in the rendering. Seems it only likes one being used.

Now works fine and can correctly use the user local settings to populate the fields.

Nice and clean now. Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

You do not want touch `InitializeComponent()`. This code is all generated by the designer.

If you want to keep things tidy, I would suggest setting any user settings within the `form_Load` event. This is called directly after the form's constructor.